# SQL script - IF mysql ELSEIF sqlserver

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I think this should be possible in some way or the other.

I need to check if the sql script is running on a mysql server or a sqlserver. The reason for that is the two different syntaxes for altering a column type.

Something like this:

```
if mysql
  ALTER TABLE table MODIFY COLUMN column_name LONG_TEXT
elseif sqlserver
  ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

So how do you check if it is a mysql or a sqlserver?

Comment: `ntext` is deprecated, use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead

Comment: Each SQL dialect has zero knowledge of others and there's no way to make a random `.sql` file smart about this. You need to do this in your application layer.

Comment: You could use conditional build and dependent on target, execute specific code. Something like C preprocessor directives: `#ifdef MySQL #else #endif`

Answer (score 1):

MySql has `ELSEIF`, T-SQL has `ELSE IF`, PLSQL has `ELSIF`, so this approach won´t work.

What´s more, SQL is typically syntax-checked before execution, and not line-by-line, as in batch files.

Answer (score 0):

The same script will not work on MySQL and SQL Server. I would recommend to move this logic on application layer or shell/powershell script.